# passing data from a csv file to a line chart | KOTLIN

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I have a line chart from the MPAndroidChart library and I want its data to be updated with the data from the scv file. Someone could show me how to do it or show me a library where I could do it. I am a beginner and I don't know how to go about it

the page from which I made the chart [here](https://medium.com/@yilmazvolkan/kotlinlinecharts-c2a730226ff1)

my MainActivity.kt

```
    package com.example.aplikacjadlataty

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Switch
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.Easing
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


//1
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_loadCsv)
        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)

        val sw1 = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.switch1)
        sw1?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            else screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

            if (isChecked) layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            else layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

            if (isChecked) AdsLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            else AdsLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

            if (isChecked) text.text = "Set light mode"
            else text.text = "Set dark mode"
            if (isChecked) text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            else text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)

            if (isChecked) button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            else button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            if (isChecked) button.setBackgroundColor(R.color.DGray)
            else button.setBackgroundColor(R.color.LGray)
        }






//2
        Log.d(
            "MainActivity", "onCreate Called \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "    __  ___    ___     __ __   _____          ______    __  __   ____        __    _   __    ____    ___     __ __  \n" +
                    "   /  |/  /   /   |   / //_/  / ___/         / ____/   / / / /  / __ \\      / /   / | / /   /  _/   /   |   / //_/ \n" +
                    "  / /|_/ /   / /| |  / ,<     \\__ \\         / /       / /_/ /  / / / / __  / /   /  |/ /    / /    / /| |  / ,<   \n" +
                    " / /  / /   / ___ | / /| |   ___/ /        / /___    / __  /  / /_/ / / /_/ /   / /|  /   _/ /    / ___ | / /| |    \n" +
                    "/_/  /_/   /_/  |_|/_/ |_|  /____/         \\____/   /_/ /_/   \\____/  \\____/   /_/ |_/   /___/   /_/  |_|/_/ |_| \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                    \n" +
                    "                                                                                                                      "
        )






//3
        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}






//4
        val lineChart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.lineChart)

        val entries = ArrayList<Entry>()

        entries.add(Entry(1f, 3.4121f))
        entries.add(Entry(2f, 3.8195f))
        entries.add(Entry(3f, 3.8253f))
        entries.add(Entry(4f, 3.9150f))
        entries.add(Entry(5f, 4f))
        entries.add(Entry(6f, 3.5252f))
        entries.add(Entry(7f, 3.8956f))
        entries.add(Entry(8f, 3.8561f))
        entries.add(Entry(9f, 4.0200f))
        entries.add(Entry(10f, 3.0392f))
        entries.add(Entry(11f, 3.0420f))
        entries.add(Entry(12f, 3.5034f))
        entries.add(Entry(13f, 4.3270f))
        entries.add(Entry(14f, 4.6201f))
        entries.add(Entry(15f, 3.9295f))
        entries.add(Entry(16f, 3.7232f))
        entries.add(Entry(17f, 3.0725f))
        entries.add(Entry(18f, 3.5252f))
        entries.add(Entry(19f, 4.0371f))
        entries.add(Entry(20f, 3.5252f))
        entries.add(Entry(21f, 4.1403f))
        entries.add(Entry(22f, 4.4237f))
        entries.add(Entry(23f, 3.8392f))
        entries.add(Entry(24f, 3.5252f))

        val vl = LineDataSet(entries, "USD/PLN")

        vl.setDrawValues(false)
        vl.setDrawFilled(true)
        vl.lineWidth = 3f
        vl.fillColor = R.color.gray
        vl.fillAlpha = R.color.red

        lineChart.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 0f

        lineChart.data = LineData(vl)

        lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.axisMaximum = 24 + 0.1f

        lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true)
        lineChart.setPinchZoom(true)

        lineChart.description.text = "Hour"
        lineChart.setNoDataText("No forex yet!")

        lineChart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)

        val markerView = CustomMarker(this@MainActivity, R.layout.marker_view)
        lineChart.marker = markerView







//5  p1
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_loadCsv)?.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            intent.type = "text/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

//5  p2
    companion object {
        const val READ_REQUEST_CODE = 123
    }
}
```

csv file

```
84500;2238
84500;2238
84500;2238
84500;2238
84500;2238
84500;2238
84500;2238
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as a two-part problem:

1. Provide a way for the user to select the CSV file on their device. This can be done easily using Storage Access Framework.
2. Actually read the CSV file line-by-line. The OpenCSV library makes this pretty easy.

[This link walks you through both issues.](https://aknay.github.io/2018/09/28/how-to-open-a-csv-file-from-android.html)

And if you need to learn more about Storage Access Framework, [I recommend this link](https://en.proft.me/2018/05/24/using-android-storage-access-framework/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236366/discussion-on-answer-by-gavin-wright-passing-data-from-a-csv-file-to-a-line-char).